# Placing 64bits address on the stack

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64

How can I place a 64bit long address on the stack?
I have this currently:

```
//setup the stack
push rbp;
mov rbp, rsp;
sub rsp, 80; //80 bytes for stack, 9 args of 64 bits + 64 bits for the function address

mov qword [rbp - 72], 0xfefefefe12345678; // <--- won't work
call [rbp - 72];

//Restore stack
mov rsp, rbp;
pop rbp;
ret 80; // <---- Is this correct?
```

Also, is the `ret` correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to use a 64-bit immediate is with a move into a register.  So you could do:

```
mov rax, 0xfefefefe12345678
mov qword [rbp - 72], rax
```

If you really can't touch any register, you could save/restore the register around the move

```
push rax
mov rax, 0xfefefefe12345678
mov qword [rbp - 72], rax
pop rax
```

or you could turn it into two moves

```
mov dword [rbp - 72], 0x12345678
mov dword [rbp - 68], 0xfefefefe
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the second option is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Btw, how would then my call work? Will ```call [rbp - 72]``` read 4 or 8 bytes?

Comment: A `call` instruction will always read 8-byte addresses in 64-bit mode.  A `call immed` uses only a 32-bit immediate, so can only call targets within +/-2GB of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

There's a push-immediate command, but it can't take a 64-bit immediate operatn. Use a register:

```
mov rax, 0xfefefefe12345678
push rax
```

As for ret 80, no, it's not right. The `sub rsp, 80` line is undone by the `mov rsp, rbp` line. The only reason to use a parameter with `ret` is to remove the function parameters in callee-clears-stack calling conventions.

Comment: But for the push to work I'd have to push 9 times before actually pushing the address, right? I don't want to do that (or am I forced?). Ok, I'll fix the ret :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to call something at that address, why push? do `mov rax, 0xaddress/call rax`.

Comment: I need the registers, so I need to use some memory from the stack. Hmmm... but maybe I could try using rax, as that's not expected to be used

Comment: Nope, I just re-thought that, can't use %rax. In fact, I can't touch any registers at all, so I'm forced to use the stack.

Comment: According to Intel's docs, `push` does not support 64-bit immediate values (though it does not specify what happens if you give it a 64-bit operand size prefix).  The only instruction that is documented to support 64-bit immediates is `mov reg,immed`

Comment: @ChrisDodd so I would need to do ```mov``` twice?

Comment: You're clobbering rbp and rsp at the very least. Please clarify the "can't touch the registers" rule.

Comment: Please see for what I was asking in the answer I just accepted :)  Sorry for not being more specific